# Can't get JQuery loaded in my project

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3

JQuery is included by jquery-rails https://github.com/rails/jquery-rails

I don't know why, but i can't execute any jquery method in google chrome dev console.

But i'm sure i included jquery in my code

```
<script src="/assets/jquery.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery-ui.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery_ujs.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

All links open!!!

But,

```
> $(".multiple-select")
null
```

even i have it in code

```
<input class="multiple-select" id="some_id" type="text" value="[405]" />
```

Also

```
> window.jQuery
undefined
```

**Update:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    console.log("class");
    $(".multiple-select").select2();
});
```

Produces in console:

TypeError: $(...).select2 is not a function active_admin-select.js:3
"class"

Answer (score 0):

Are you enclosing your code in the following?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // your code here
});
```

jQuery may not have loaded when you are trying to call it...

http://api.jquery.com/ready/